# Obtener columna nombre de una tabla a partir de otra tabla relacionada a la misma por ids

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

tengo una cuestion, he creado 2 tablas, una llamada Marcas y otra llamada Productos, en la tabla marcas tengo idMarca y en la tabla de Productos también tengo idMarca como llave foranea.
Estoy usando un foreach a mis datos de la tabla de productos y quisiera reemplazar los numeros de idMarca por los nombres equivalentes a esos id dentro de la tabla marcas.
Esta es la tabla marcas de la cual quiero extraer los nombres.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la tabla de productos en la cual quiero que se reemplacen los idMarca por los nombres de la marca
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui les dejo el codigo que use en esas secciones, primero la de productos

```
<table class="datos">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID producto</th>
                <th>Nombre producto</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>ID marca</th>
            </tr>

            <tbody>
                <!-- Mostrar producto -->
                <?php foreach($productos as $producto):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $producto->idProducto; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $producto->nombreProducto; ?></td>
                        <td>
                        <?php 
                        // Aplicamos la funcion para acortar la descripcion a 30 caracteres
                        $descripcionChica = truncate($producto->descripcion, 30);

                        echo $descripcionChica;
                        ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $producto->precio; ?></td>
                        <!-- Aca debajo quiero que es vez de ser el id sea el nombre --> 
                        <td><?php echo $producto->idMarca; ?></td>
                        <td> 
                            <form method="POST" class="w-100" action="/producto/eliminar">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $producto->idProducto; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="producto">
                                <input type="submit" class="boton-rojo-block" value="Eliminar">
                            </form>
                            <a href="/producto/actualizar?id=<?php echo $producto->idProducto; ?>" class="boton-azul-block">Actualizar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Ahora la de marcas

```
 <table class="datos">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID marca</th>
                <th>Nombre Marca</th>
            </tr>

            <tbody>
                <!-- Mostrar marcas -->
                <?php foreach($marcas as $marca):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $marca->idMarca; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $marca->nombreMarca;?></td>
                    <td> 
                        <form method="POST" class="w-100" action="/marcas/eliminar">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $marca->idMarca; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="marca">
                            <input type="submit" class="boton-rojo-block" value="Eliminar">
                        </form>
                        <a href="/marcas/actualizar?id=<?php echo $marca->idMarca; ?>" class="boton-azul-block">Actualizar</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Les dejo foto de la base de datos por si no se entendio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacerlo con un [Joins (uniones)](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php) y Seria algo así

```
SELECT P.id, P.nombre, P.descripcion, P.precio, M.nombre AS marca
FROM productos P
INNER JOIN marcas M ON m.id = P.id_marca
```

Comment: Muchas gracias OCHOA me funciono